# Are there specific names for airport vehicles used for de-icing?

Tags: ground-operations, deice, airport-vehicles

Do de-icing vehicles used at airports for de-/anti-icing procedures have special names? I-ve searched the internet but have not found the exact names of these vehicles.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell they don't have their own name specifically they are part of the airports Ground Support Equipment. They have non-powered and powered support equipment, De/anti-icing vehicles fall under the powered category. Trying to find a better link than the one I found on Wikipedia [In case you want to see that link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_support_equipment#De/anti-icing_vehicles)
In case you want to buy one [Heres a manufacturers website of GSE](https://www.aerospecialties.com/product-category/aircraft-deicing-anti-icing-service-equipment/deicers-anti-icers-deicing-anti-icing-service/)